# get the type of input and cast it in Angular

Tags: angular

I am passing `@Input() element` variable to the `app-child` component

```
<app-child [element]="element"></app-child>
```

`element` is an object. It can be of many types, lets say `Blue`, `Red` or `Green`

Inside `ChildComponent.ts`, how can I determine the type of  `element` and cast it to the correct type? `instanceof` cannot be used with variables of type `any`.

```
`ChildComponent.ts`

@Input() element: any; // is it of type Blue, Red or Green?
```

Comment: What do you mean cast it? Could you give a less abstract illustration of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I've added a ChildComponent.ts code.

Comment: That's not demonstrating any casting. As far as determining the type, have you read e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards? If it can be `Blue`, `Red` or `Green` why type it as `any`? You might as well not be using TS.

Comment: To what should it be typed then, if it can be Blue, Red or Green? See the problem?

Comment: ...`Blue | Red | Green`? Or perhaps they have a common supertype?

Comment: Woaa,  variable can be of multiple types in Typescript? as in.. variable : Blue | Red | Green; This is my first time seeing this syntax.

Comment: "Union" types, yes; I suggest you read more of that page.

Comment: Thats awesome. thanks buddy. Make sure you post an answer.

Comment: You don't need an answer, it's in the docs; just delete the question

Comment: naah, lets leave it for the future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if only Red, Blue and Green values are permitted, it might be clearer to declare element as such:

```
@Input() element: Red | Blue | Green;
```

How you can determine the type depends on what kind of types Red, Blue or Green are. If they are classes, you can use the trusty `instanceof` operator:

```
if (this.element instanceof Red) {
    const red: Red = this.element; // no cast necessary in if-block
}
```

If they are interfaces, that doesn't work because typescript interfaces do not survive transpilation to JavaScript. You [can test a member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) though:

```
if ((<Red> this.element).reddishMember) {
    const red = <Red> this.element;
}
```